# Union of disjoint countable sets is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $S_1$ , $S_2$ are disjoint countable sets of T .Then their union is countable

**ATTEMPT**

Let 
$S_1$ = ${x_1 ,x_2,...}$

$S_2$ = ${y_1,y_2,...}$

I am thinking of making pairs by doing $S_1 \times S_2$ ,but i donot know what to do furthure .Need hints

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I am writing $S_1,S_2$ as

$S_1=\{a_{11},a_{12},a_{13},...\}$

$S_2=\{a_{21},a_{22},a_{23},...\}$.Then Listing,

$S_1\cup S_2=\{a_{11};a_{12},a_{21};a_{13},a_{22};a_{23},...\}$

Now defining the map, $f:S_1\cup S_2\to\Bbb N$, by

$$f(a_{pq}) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $p=1=q$ } \\
\{2(p+q)-5+p\}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$,Which is an enumeration ,Hence $S_1\cup S_2$ is countable

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Identify $S_1$ with the set of odd numbers and $S_2$ with the set of even numbers.

Comment: yes i was thinking about that earlier ,but there i can see two mappings but here mappings are not given .I need to give mapping from my side .Can you guide bit furthure

Comment: Countable means we have a mapping (by which I mean a bijection) from $S_1$ to $\Bbb N$.  Make a mapping from $\Bbb N$ to the odds, and combine the two to get what you want.

Comment: I am thinking of this as a two rows and infinite columm matrix .A function which assigns $a_{11}$ to 1 and $a_{21}$ to 2 ,$a_{12}$ to 3 and so on i bijection .What you have to say about that ?

Comment: isn't it infinite countable if the mapping is a bijection? Vs. finite countable if injection only?

Comment: @JPG yes, that's ultimately the kind of thing we're going for here.

Comment: @Fluffy12 terminology varies.  Rudin, for example, takes "at most countable" to mean "finite or countably infinite" an "countable" to mean "countably infinite."

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Is this a technical proof ?

Comment: It's only technical if you explicitly construct the bijection from $\{1,2\} \times \Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$.  It's not too hard, though.  We can take:
$$
f(i,j) = i + 2(j-1)
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom you have made explicit function for my matrix idea .Is i,j denotes row and columm element of matrix ?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes i have seen it ,it covers all elements of matrix .How did you come upon likt this ?